# Mapping database columns to excel spreadsheet

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, excel, database-design

I have a table that contains ~100 columns and I have to generate an excel sheet out of it. The output excel columns are like "**Total Actual FY SY-2/SY-1**" and I can't have that as my database column for sure.

My question is how can I map database columns to excel columns? How can I know for example if "TotalActualFYSY2SY1" in database should be "Total Actual FY SY-2/SY-1" in excel? 
Should I have another table to map the database column names to the excel column names?

I'm not asking for solution in any specific programming language.

(The system is going to be developed using SoftwareAG WebMethods)

Comment: `alter table add [Total Actual FY SY-2/SY-1] int`

Comment: MySQL:  surround the column name with backtics (`).

Answer (score 1):

There are various solution to this, you can do the same via using alias name in SQL Server for example

```
SELECT TotalActualFYSY2SY1 AS 'Total Actual FY SY-2/SY-1'
FROM YourTable
```

This will output your column in desired name. Alias name in SQL is the temporary name to assign to the column or table.

Another way is to fetch rows from SQL Server and change the column name from any programming language itself.

Comment: I don't think alias is going to workout since the query itself is going to be generated dynamically. What about Ivan's solution to use brackets for column names?

Comment: Yes, you can use the same but that is quite difficult for developers to write query against your database. They will be then forced to drag drop column name from SSMS or they have to use query designer to get the correct name. Also, in SQL Server column name is navarchar(128). So, you can only have characters which supports nvarchar. I would still recommend you to have readable column name and generate their alias name at runtime. and yes, you can alias name in dynamic SQL also.

Comment: Though, SQL allows you to have special characters in your column name but as a developer I recommend you to "don't break the rule" and force your developers to use [] every time. :)

Comment: Yea I think brackets would be the better solution for me now. Thanks